# DHCP client keeps stopping on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, dhcpcd

On my rasbperry pi (4b 8GB version) DHCP keeps stopping seemingly at random. I can restart it from the terminal (sudo dhcpcd) and it works fine, for a while, and then it stops again. What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

**To clarify how I determined that DHCPCD is no longer running:**

- Wifi select is unavailable, says "dhcpcd not running"
- HTOP doesn't list a DHCPCD process, even running it as root
- `dhcpcd -y 0` doesn't do anything (usually it would restart DHCPCD) but running `sudo dhcpcd` seems to start it and allows me to connect to wifi
- Anything requiring wifi (SSH, xrdp-VNC, and Samba) immediately ceases to function as soon as this "crashing" behavior is exhibited

Distribution: Raspbian OS 10 (Debian Stretch-based, I believe)
DHCPCD version: 8.1.2
Compiled features: INET ARP ARPing IPv4LL INET6 HHCPv6 AUTH
I have not modified the config file at all, this is a fresh installation of Raspbian

Last 16 log lines (hostname has been censored here):
Jun 14 19:16:46 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00 claims 192.168.0.230
Jun 14 19:17:06 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00 claims 192.168.0.230
(above line repeated 11 more times)
Jun 14 19:41:26 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: 10 second defence failed for 192.168.0.23
Jun 14 19:41:26 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.0.0/24
Jun 14 19:41:26 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.0.1

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. Please provide more info, such as the output of dhcpcd before and during the crash. You can run it in the foreground with debugging output enabled by passing the `--nobackground --debug` options, or check your system logs.

Comment: In theory you're capturing the logs from `dhcpcd` somewhere. These may contain a clue about why it has exited.

Comment: `DHCP keeps stopping` does not make sense ... did you mean to say `DHCP server keeps stopping`?

Comment: you'd practically never start dhcpd manually; you would start it as a service, and then let your OS (in this case, systemd) take care of managing it, including restarts if necessary. Why are you starting dhcpd yourself? Also, I'm having a very hard time imagining a situation where the default config of dhcpd is useful to anyone. So, aside from logs, maybe tell us your *motivation* behind running dhcpd!

Comment: sceox I'll do that when I have a moment, and i'll copy the output to here
larsks See above comment to @sceox
jsotola I renamed the question to make that more clear. You were right, I said the wrong thing
Marcus Müller I usually don't run it manually, Raspbian runs it at startup fine, until it seemingly exits. I'm still using DHCPCD because when it works, it just works, except for when it doesn't. It's good enough for what I need it to do, usually

Answer (score 1):

You said, *"DHCP keeps stopping seemingly at random"*, but you didn't say how you determined that it is "stopping". I suspect that it's not stopping at all, but that it is `forking to run in the background` (ref `man dhcpcd`). You can confirm (or deny) that as follows:

Check the `systemd` logs w/ `journalctl` & scroll to the bottom of the pager to find the most current entries:

```bash
journalctl --unit=dhcpcd | less

... [scroll to end of pager ...]

-- Boot 5687a151f68246acbe8c6bd12cd0798e --
Jun 09 09:52:46 raspberrypi3b systemd[1]: Starting DHCP Client Daemon...
Jun 09 09:52:46 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: dev: loaded udev
Jun 09 09:52:46 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[465]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Jun 09 09:52:46 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd-run-hooks[479]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Jun 09 09:52:47 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Jun 09 09:52:47 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jun 09 09:52:47 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Jun 09 09:52:53 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Jun 09 09:52:53 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `Mesh01'
Jun 09 09:52:53 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease (requesting 192.168.1.143)
Jun 09 09:52:53 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: offered 192.168.1.143 from 192.168.1.1
Jun 09 09:52:53 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.1.143/24
Jun 09 09:52:58 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: leased 192.168.1.143 for 7200 seconds
Jun 09 09:52:58 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Jun 09 09:52:58 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Jun 09 09:52:58 raspberrypi3b dhcpcd[374]: forked to background, child pid 606
Jun 09 09:52:58 raspberrypi3b systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client Daemon.
```

This sequence above shows what `dhcpcd` has logged since the last boot - which is *typical* for `dhcpcd` in my experience.

Note the entry `forked to background, child pid 606`

Check that PID:

```bash
$ ps -p606 -o comm,unit,stat
COMMAND         UNIT                            STAT
dhcpcd          dhcpcd.service                  Ss
$
```

[It's *alive*!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuoKNZjr8_U)

Now - if you **do not want** `dhcpcd` to fork to the background, you may run it in the foreground by using the `-B, --nobackground` option (again, ref `man dhcpcd`). However: you should be aware now from the output of our `ps` command above that `dhcpcd` is controlled by `systemd` (i.e. RPi's *init* system), and by default it is started during the boot process. And you can safely ignore any comments re the utility of the *default* `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`; in *most cases*, `dhcpcd` runs perfectly well with the default configuration.

Comment: It is forking to run in the background, which is what I expect. What I meant was it runs fine forked in the background, typically for an extended period of time, then it just... stops. I verified it's not running because on the wifi select it says "no wireless interfaces found" or something like that, check htop, no process matching DHCPCD.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jun 14 19:16:46 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00 claims 192.168.0.230
Jun 14 19:17:06 sk******berry dhcpcd[10428]: wlan0: hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00 claims 192.168.0.230
(above line repeated 11 more times)
```

This looks like there might be a malfunctioning device within your wireless network that is causing an IP address conflict. Or perhaps your wireless network is under attack.

I haven't tried how `dhcpcd` actually reacts when under a IP address hijacking attack, but it seems to me it might look much like this.

Your `dhcpcd` [is apparently detecting](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/blob/master/src/arp.c#L157) that some other host (which apparently claims its hardware address is `00:00:00:00:00:00`, which is somewhat suspicious in itself) is claiming to have the same IP address as this system was using at the time.

`dhcpcd` is attempting to defend its claim to the IP address, but the other one doesn't back down. Trying to continue in the presence of an IP address conflict is futile, so `dhcpcd` backs down instead.

The duplicate address detection code of `dhcpcd` was apparently written with the link-local addresses (IPV4LL: 169.254.0.0/16) in mind, but it's triggering on your regular IP address. Perhaps that's what causes `dhcpcd` to exit instead of trying to get a new IP address from the DHCP server.

You might want to make sure your wireless network uses WPA2 or better protection, and change the network password to something that is not easily guessable; perhaps a neighbor within WiFi range has figured out the current password, and is now "trying to hack you like Mr. Robot in the TV".

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! Would you suggest I use a ping 192.168.0.230 from a different device when I experience this problem, to verify there is indeed something claiming that IP?

Comment: If it's someone with a Kali Linux trying to be a hacker, it's probably configured to not answer to pings by default. You might want to check `arp -a`/`ip neigh show` and/or the active WiFi client list of your router instead: responding to pings is optional, but responding to ARP requests is pretty much mandatory if the other system wants to communicate at all. `arping` might be helpful too. Or if the  `hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00` was you hiding the real MAC address, then you already know the MAC address of the offending system.

Comment: Alright, thanks. For clarity, the 00:00:00:00:00:00 is what was actually reported by the log file,